# less communal "annexes" of the apartment (Salinger's Zooey)

Tags: word-meaning

A quote from J.Salinger's Zooey:

> A  cordon  of  waist-high  bookcases  lined  three  walls,  their 
>   shelves  cram-jammed  and  literally  sagging  with  books—children's 
>   books,  textbooks,  secondhand  books,  Book  Club  books,  plus  an 
>   even  more  heterogeneous  overflow  from  **less  communal "annexes" of
>   the apartment.** ("Dracula" now stood next to "Elementary Pali,"  "The
>   Boy Allies at the Somme" stood next to "Bolts  of Melody," "The Scarab
>   Murder  Case" and "The Idiot" were together, "Nancy Drew and the
>   Hidden Staircase" lay on top  of "Fear and Trembling.")

What could he refer to as "less communal annexes of the apartment"?

Comment: *less communal* means less shared by the public, [of or relating to a community](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/communal). An [annex](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/annex) is a building added on to a larger one or an auxiliary building situated near a main one, or a smaller structure added on, such as a wing.

Comment: @Susan: so he probably referred to books gathered from individual rooms of the apartment, i.e. reflecting individual tastes?

Comment: That's exactly right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Less [communal](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/communal)” means less “shared by the people of a community”; less “public”.

An [annex](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/annex) is “a building added on to a larger one[,] an auxiliary building situated near a main one”, or a smaller structure added on, such as a wing.

He is probably referring to books gathered from other peoples’ rooms adjoining the apartment (that reflect individual tastes).